# How to show the Project Explorer window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Suddenly my project explorer window has disappeared from Eclipse. I try selecting Windows > Show View > Project Explorer, but nothing happens. What can I do?

Comment: it should have been in minimized state.

Comment: Can I use a key combination for maximize it? Because, when I select Windows > Show Windows > Project Explorer something take the focus ( probably the project explorer window)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Try `Window` --> `Perspective` --> `Reset Perspective...`. Remember that your own settings, if any, will also be reset.

Comment: Wow, that's a universal solution. Nice option when eclipse views somehow get screwed up!

Answer (score 67):

Try to close Eclipse IDE and reopen it and

click on window->show view->project explorer

Comment: Done! But the problem persists.

Comment: do one thing click on window->Reset prespective this should work

Comment: It helps, but explorer appeared on the bottom of the window. Drag&drop to the left side solved this :)

Answer (score 46):

For me it was like this...

**Window->Show View->Other->General->Project Explorer**

Or

**Window->Open Perspective->Other->Java (default)**

Comment: This is the most correct answer here. Why would I want to reset my perspective?

Answer (score 21):

Open Eclipse IDE
[image: E]
 Enter "**Project Explorer**" on Quick Access (Search text box).
Either select from drop-down or press Enter

Comment: Only method I see that works without resetting your current view.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked.   It seems like a dumb thing, but why would Project Explorer be so hard to find?  What's the point of hiding something like that behind multiple layers of menu?

Answer (score 10):

1. > Window -> Perspective -> Reset
2. > Reset the IDE
3. > Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer

[image]

Comment: How is that different than 'Windows > Show View > Project Explorer' in the question?

Answer (score 6):

Select **Window->Show View**, if it is not shown there then select **other**. Under **General** you can see **Project Explorer**.

Answer (score 6):

If none of the above solutions work, Try Window-> New Window

Answer (score 4):

I had encountered the same problem as well. The following solution helped me to get over it:

Window -> Show View -> Package Explorer.

You can use the shortcut as well. It's Alt + Shift + Q, P

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest Luna upgrade.
The only solution that worked was Window >> New Window.
It's very easy to lose that critical bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on either Eclipse or Spring tool suite then follow the below steps.

(1) Go to 'Window' on the top of the editor. Click on it
(2) Select show view. You should see an option 'Project Explorer'. Click on it.
You should be able to do it.

[image]

Comment: How is that different than 'Windows > Show View > Project Explorer' in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Close the current perspective:
[image: Close the current perspective]

Reopen it using **Window** -> **Open perspective**.

Answer (score 0):

i had also encountered this issue.
.
This Solution worked for me....

windows->navigation->maximize active View or Editor(ctrl + M)
.
in the screen you can see on left side navigation menus ... now click on those buttons one by one ....you will get your solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the perspective to JavaEE and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is problem but, this ticked me off for a while since I did not realize what was happening at first - maybe this will help others.

Its not really a problem, just the way Eclipse works. (I'm use to Visual studio)
Its all about Perspectives!

I set up an (existing) PHP project in eclipse(neon) and then tried to configure and run debug.  A Popup "Confirm Perspective Switch" is shown - I selected "Yes", not realizing what it actually does.  The "perspective" then changes and you no longer see the project explorer anywhere.  You cant "open" the project explorer window from top nav > window > show view,  since its no longer there (which is BS, it should show something that gives you indication of current and other "perspectives" - at least for newbie.)  No where now does it give project explore options.

Now you must change the "perspective" back from debug to PHP (at least in in my case).

This can be done a couple ways, easiest is from the icons on right top right side side.  One icon would be the "bug", and next to it is the PHP icon.  Just click the icon "perspective" you want.  The other way is from top nav bar > window > Perspective > open Perspective, then select PHP.   Could they hide this any deeper?

I know this is likely second nature to those who have used eclipse for a while, but was frustrating to me (on day one) till I figured out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please Select window in tool bar
2. Move to show view
3. Select project explorer

Comment: How is that different than 'Windows > Show View > Project Explorer' in the question?

Answer (score 0):

applied the same method to reset the perspective, no changes appaired then I restart the Eclipse IDE which was fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Perspective -> Reset Perspective..

[image]