# Can't see project explorer in STM32CubeIDE

Tags: eclipse, stm32cubeide

I have a little newbie problem here, I was working whit STM32CubeIDE, then (I guess I press some button or something like that) the project Explorer disappeared, currently I'm only able to open in if I open the debug perspective, If I open the C/C++ perspective the project explorer don't show up, I tried to open it by going to Windows -> Show view -> Project explorer, but when I click on it, anything happens.

This is getting frustrating because I have to switch to debug perspective every time I want to open or add a file

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: just as a note, I was able to "solve" this creating a new workspace

Comment: Does _Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective..._ fix your issue?

Comment: @howlger it does!
Can you put your comment as an answer to solve this question?

Comment: Great. Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19164931/6505250